# Unable to get updated URL from Config.Properties file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Why properties file is not getting updated in Web App?

```
public TestBase() {
    try {
        prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/e5570104/eclipse-workspace/ClientPortalNewTest"
            + "/src/main/java/com/qa/config/Config.Properties");

        prop.load(file);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Why are you expecting them updated, which Web App are you talking about and what has your piece of code to do with that web app?

Comment: Welcome. Have a look at [how to ask](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/asking). As it stands your question is vague.

Answer (score 1):

Use an external properties file for overriding your "Property.prop" file settings. You can pull this off for example as follows. Assume that the default property values are bundled in your WAR and the modified values are saved to some other path, which is defined using a system property - let say it's called CONFIG_LOCATION. Now after loading your properties from the bundle you read them also from this external "overrides.prop" file - this overrides your defaults from "Property.prop":

```
 PropertiesConfiguration pc1=new PropertiesConfiguration(a); 
    try(
FileReader propReader = new FileReader(System.getenv().get("CONFIG_FILES") +"/overrides.prop"){ pc1.load(propReader); 
}
```

When you need to save changes, you do that to "overrides.prop" - this will save all the properties, not only the changed ones, but that should have no negative effects.